# getting heap corruption detected when freeing memory with calloc and changed stdout

Tags: c, heap-memory, heap-corruption

I am trying to change the stdout into a file, write something and than retrun it back to screen. My code is :

```
FILE *stream ;
char * file_name = "LRA_SOLVER";
char * file_ext = ".txt";
char file_number [3] = {0};
itoa (lra_solver_couter++,file_number,10);
char* file_full_name = (char*)calloc(strlen(file_number)+10+4,sizeof(char));
strcpy(file_full_name, file_name);
strcat(file_full_name, file_number);
strcat(file_full_name, file_ext); 
if((stream = freopen(file_full_name, "w", stdout)) == NULL)
    exit(-1);
print(); // a lot of printing into the file.
stream = freopen("CON", "w", stdout); // change it back
free(file_full_name);
```

but I am getting the error heap corruption detected... the lra_solver_couter isn't big (usually 0-20).
What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Quite often when you get "heap corruption", it is ANOTHER object that either was freed earlier, or allocated later, that causes the problem, not the actual object being freed.

Comment: You could prove that by using a stack-based string variable (I would do that anyway, as filenames are typically fairly limited in size, so `char file_full_name[PATH_MAX];` should work for any sane path).

Comment: why you use `stream = freopen("CON", "w", stdout); // change it back` ?

Comment: Have you tried running this code with valgrind?

Comment: @arne: Does valgrind work on Windows? Since when?

Comment: @MatsPetersson I don't think there's a windows version yet, although http://sourceforge.net/p/valgrind4win/wiki/ProjectStatus/ looks a little promising. OP didn't state windows though, hence I suggested valgrind.

Comment: Now when digging up old post like this to edit, maybe check: Is it otherwise correctly tagged? Is it a super common FAQ that could as well just be dupe hammered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot the terminating '\0' when you calculate the needed length of `file_full_name`:
You only have `strlen(file_number)+10+4` with `10 == strlen(file_name)` and `4 == strlen(file_ext)`. Add `1` for `\0'.